# Laravel gives an error when running tests

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, testing

When I run the `php artisan test` command, the terminal outputs the error

> PHPUnit requires the "dom", "json", "libxml", "mbstring", "tokenizer", "xml", "xmlwriter" extensions, but the "mbstring" extension is not available.

In trying to install the dependencies with the command

```bash
apt --fix-broken install
```

The terminal gives an error:

> Failed to connect to tr.archive.ubuntu.com:80 (193.140.98.183). - connect (113: No route to the node)

What could it be and how do I run the tests?

Comment: What does `apt-get update` show? Looks like your machine fails to connect to Ubuntu repo mirror. You might try changing inaccessible mirror by editing `/etc/apt/sources.list` file and then install a missing `mbstring` PHP extension.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the tags you provided, you might be using ubuntu. You can try running this script in your terminal to install mbstring:

`sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring`

Answer found in this [SO](https://askubuntu.com/a/731380/1112978) . This would depend on the version of your PHP.

Comment: You could just link answer in comments. Other than that, you can't be sure in PHP version and this answer is probably wrong [because of that].

Comment: Better to run `apt install php-mbstring` and let it install the right one for his version